# How to set attributes / add children to a node in a nodelist

Tags: xml, xpath, set

I need to add children and set the attribute for a node where it is the second instance in a family of nodes.
But I cant seem to find a way to "SelectSingleNode" so that I can add children and set attributes.
This is what I have created so far:

```
<Markers ObjectID="22" ClassID="bee50706-b524-416c-9f03-b596ce5f6866" Version="2">
    <Markers Version="1" ObjectRef="24">
        <Marker Version="1" Index="0">
            <Second ObjectRef="23"/>
            <First>5009872344</First>
        </Marker>
        <Marker/>
    </Markers>
    <Node Version="1"/>
</Markers>
```

I cant get any further because I cant set the attribute of the second instance of the node "Marker". Everything I try sets the first instance of "Marker" and replaces what it already has.

This is what I need to end up with:

```
<Markers ObjectID="22" ClassID="bee50706-b524-416c-9f03-b596ce5f6866" Version="2">
   <Markers Version="1">
      <Marker Version="1" Index="0">
         <Second ObjectRef="23"/>
         <First>5009119315200</First>
      </Marker>
      <Marker Version="1" Index="1">
         <Second ObjectRef="24"/>
         <First>419274305049600</First>
      </Marker>
   </Markers>
   <Node Version="1"/>
</Markers>
```

A nodelist of `//Markers[@ObjectID='22']/Markers/Marker` produces 2 items in the list.
I am trying to figure out how to reference a single node from this list but I just cant figure out how.

Is there a way to identify a node that has no attributes???
Thanks for your help

Comment: Show us some code that doesn't work, and we can tell you what's wrong with it. At the moment we don't even know what programming language you are using - Java, C#, XSLT, XQuery???? Downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is really to get the 2nd `<Marker>` within the same parent, you can use xpath index to achieve that like so :

```
//Markers[@ObjectID='22']/Markers/Marker[2]
```

Another possible way, as you asked, by getting `<Marker>` node not having any attribute :

```
//Markers[@ObjectID='22']/Markers/Marker[not(@*)]
```